# Having Curl post request error to Laravel app [Somethin Went Wrong* Closing connection 0]

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Hey guys having a hard time with cURL. I've setup a laravel app with the followin controller

controller.php

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){

        $credentials = $request->only('email','password');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return 'Auth Passed';
        }
        else{
            return 'Somethin Went Wrong';
        }
```

and it works completely fine with postman

but my cURL cli post request just don't work

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt -vX POST http://localhost:8000/login/auth \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Accept:application/json" \
-H "X-CSRF-TOKEN:gC2Kkq50HIcoRJ2d2yzKf6cPOhqVJaQRYSyDh2GJ" \
-d "{"email":"email@gmail.com","password":"pass"}"
```

The Connection just closes without processing the request with the following error

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /login/auth HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IitseTV2bm45OUMwcTQ2R25hMEdtQlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia2twVmRUTTFNMEFTekxaL2gyUmNhbGE1YTZZMm5LeVZxWU5lMDdrTE9uQzkwKzVvTGVtdU9SaEh1c1BncDViSStmb0luZEs1TnNUTDVhQXRNWTE1UVpUV1ZiWWs3bHVYYmFPWmZheFJIMTBOc0VJRDZrZ3RGTWFLbHc3YnZHUksiLCJtYWMiOiJmYTMyZjY4ZjJjODQyOTgxZGYzODlkZjZkYjllZjliZmYxZjBjMDIzYWVhOTU3MDMzNDAwNjAwZDgyODE1ZjYzIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjB0c1hGVXhxSjBQdzNPR3Z5UUI4eGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ0RQbEc0TXJuT1RFTy9GZFVJWi9qUUpHeXdxUGQyZEwxeGVHZis2cDBhdnVnVWQ5VVNEckkydDU3TG42S3ZqdFM4ZWNXcnYxOXZCTGc1V2FjaDNwL2U5SlU0cU5UWjRWQytOTkR2dlBucjk5REx4NHNsTlNUMXExYXUzbStJcVciLCJtYWMiOiJkMWE5MTNmMmE4Mzc3MTZmNTY2N2Y5OTYyMTUzMDE4MzI3MWE0NzE1YjMzOGFiOWZiZmNmZGI2YmI5MmI3OThlIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
> Content-Type:application/json
> Accept:application/json
> X-CSRF-TOKEN:gC2Kkq50HIcoRJ2d2yzKf6cPOhqVJaQRYSyDh2GJ
> Content-Length: 38
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8000
< Date: Thu, 19 May 2022 15:24:55 GMT
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.16
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Thu, 19 May 2022 15:24:55 GMT
* Replaced cookie XSRF-TOKEN="eyJpdiI6Ii8vZUtnS2tVTUlHY3ludEdMaHMydnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiR2d1NkZGNWIxRDRLY2YwNmtUWlhCaS9FU2pLaDVyYVVvNGZBWlJGUUhuOEltakdvMnJnY3FaMERRYnNmTGJOQVM4WFRiSGdNK1FMdDZOUXh5WGpGQ3N5cXVYSXkyM21UNkk0QVFCZFVReFB1UXE1dkhKVm1EbnQyYVBuU2lyaTciLCJtYWMiOiI5MjVlMGI3NzcwOWE0OTU5ZWFhZWFmMWE3OGI0ZDA5ODNkYWViNjI5MjMzNjYwYzhkNDRkYzk1NDlkNTliMTU3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D" for domain localhost, path /, expire 1652981095
< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ii8vZUtnS2tVTUlHY3ludEdMaHMydnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiR2d1NkZGNWIxRDRLY2YwNmtUWlhCaS9FU2pLaDVyYVVvNGZBWlJGUUhuOEltakdvMnJnY3FaMERRYnNmTGJOQVM4WFRiSGdNK1FMdDZOUXh5WGpGQ3N5cXVYSXkyM21UNkk0QVFCZFVReFB1UXE1dkhKVm1EbnQyYVBuU2lyaTciLCJtYWMiOiI5MjVlMGI3NzcwOWE0OTU5ZWFhZWFmMWE3OGI0ZDA5ODNkYWViNjI5MjMzNjYwYzhkNDRkYzk1NDlkNTliMTU3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 19-May-2022 17:24:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
* Replaced cookie laravel_session="eyJpdiI6Im45K3dlV0g5aWNDVGdNNkNHajRnMUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUXdjMVdNV0hvU3VmWHBpS2N3QnhJMmUxdWNua09RTjdrSk9mWW10MjE2dzYrd3c0Z3Y1amc0OXhUV0RqNWxiREQxV0VwcEhrUGxGcXlKVjdzc0paUHNNbGZNNFQxc2RTbm1IMi8reStNZTNaMjJCdElXT0RmYmtUVDhSNm9QdTYiLCJtYWMiOiJlZDExOTY3YzEyNmZhZjA3MzJhNDJlZmMwZTEyODQ4YTAxNjdkYjcxNmU1ZTg1YWQyOTZjMjRkZTY2YTYzN2JiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D" for domain localhost, path /, expire 1652981096
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im45K3dlV0g5aWNDVGdNNkNHajRnMUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUXdjMVdNV0hvU3VmWHBpS2N3QnhJMmUxdWNua09RTjdrSk9mWW10MjE2dzYrd3c0Z3Y1amc0OXhUV0RqNWxiREQxV0VwcEhrUGxGcXlKVjdzc0paUHNNbGZNNFQxc2RTbm1IMi8reStNZTNaMjJCdElXT0RmYmtUVDhSNm9QdTYiLCJtYWMiOiJlZDExOTY3YzEyNmZhZjA3MzJhNDJlZmMwZTEyODQ4YTAxNjdkYjcxNmU1ZTg1YWQyOTZjMjRkZTY2YTYzN2JiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 19-May-2022 17:24:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
<
Somethin Went Wrong* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Check your laravel logs, see if there's any information there. You can also try `Log::info($credentials);` before your Auth::attempt to see what it contains.

Comment: the curl request doesn't pass through Auth::attempt tried changing 
-d "{"email":"email@gmail.com","password":"pass"}"
to
-d "email=nash@gmail.com" -d "password=123456"
but still same error

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. windows single quotes don't work on windows had to change to the json part of the post request into
`-d "{\"email\":\"nash@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"123456\"}"`